# Django email attachment of file upload

Tags: django

I am trying to attach a file to an email. The file is uploaded by the user and put into the media folder.

I have tried two ways.

First:

```
def email_view(request, pk):
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=pk)
    email_to = person.email
    email = EmailMessage(
        'Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'email@email.com', [email_to])
    email.attach_file(person.upload)
    email.send()

    return redirect('home')
```

This gives me an error `'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'rfind'`

Second:

```
def email_view(request, pk):
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=pk)
    email_to = person.email

    attachment = str(person.upload)
    attachment = 'http://my_site:8080/media/' + attachment.replace('./', '')
    email = EmailMessage(
        'Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'email@email.com', [email_to])
    email.attach_file(attachment)
    email.send()

    return redirect('home')
```

This gives me a page not found. If i copy the url from the error though it takes me to the file. I assume this is happening because of the string format

Comment: try `redirect('/home')`

Comment: The redirect is not the issue. It refers to the url name. It works without the attachment part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you pass FileField object to attach_file method, not file path. Try to change it to:

```
email.attach_file(person.upload.file.name)
```

Comment: didn't work. I get `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'http://my_site:8080/media/uploads/test.pdf'`. It is definitely there though as if i copy and past the url it takes me to the file

Comment: @DimaKudosh  Hi, how did you resoled the file does not exist error. Same is happening with me. i can open the file in browser but gives a error no file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error of file not found. This is the tweak I used:

```py
from django.conf import settings
import os

filename = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, person.upload.file.name)
email.attach_file(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much cleaner solution. path already contains the absolute path to the file so no need to do os.joins or other concatenations

```
    email.attach_file(person.upload.file.path)
```